# Reversing a double linked list using recusion

Tags: c++

So I am trying to debug my code to reverse a double-linked list. It runs correctly, but for some reason, when I try to assign the front -> next = front -> prev. It gives to next to NULL, which occurs because NULL is behind the first element of the linked list. I am trying to figure out a way to overcome this issue.

```
void List::reverse(Node *front) //front == head
{
  cout << "Head: " << front << endl;
  if(front == NULL)
  {
    cout << "Head is NULL" << endl;
    return;
  }

  Node *temp = front->next;
  cout << "Node *temp = front -> next: " << temp << endl;

  front -> next = front -> prev;
  cout << "front -> next = front -> prev: " << front->next << endl;

  front -> prev = temp;
  cout << "front -> prev = temp: " << front->prev << endl;

  cout << "-------" << endl;

  if(front->prev == NULL)
  {
    cout << "front->prev: " << front ->prev << endl;
    cout << "ITS BEEN REVERSED" << endl;
    return;
  }

  reverse(front->prev);
}
```

The error is **front -> next = front -> prev**

The List I'm using for an example is

`["Hello", "Human", "test", "Boo"]`

With the code above, this is what outputs within the console as I was debugging this.

```
Reverse Test Below:
--------------
Before Reversed: [Hello, Human, test, Boo]
Head: 0x55a98ae172c0
Node *temp = front -> next: 0x55a98ae17300
front -> next = front -> prev: 0
front -> prev = temp: 0x55a98ae17300
-------
Head: 0x55a98ae17300
Node *temp = front -> next: 0x55a98ae17340
front -> next = front -> prev: 0
front -> prev = temp: 0x55a98ae17340
-------
Head: 0x55a98ae17340
Node *temp = front -> next: 0x55a98ae17380
front -> next = front -> prev: 0
front -> prev = temp: 0x55a98ae17380
-------
Head: 0x55a98ae17380
Node *temp = front -> next: 0
front -> next = front -> prev: 0
front -> prev = temp: 0
-------
front->prev: 0
ITS BEEN REVERSED
---
After Reversed: [Hello]
--------------
```

I think everything else is pretty okay; I just dont know how to change the

`front -> next = front -> prev`

Comment: You should really search the internet for "C++ reverse doubly linked list" and compare your result with the others.

Comment: I highly recommend using a debugger *and drawing pictures of the list as you go along*.  If we were to help, that's what we would do.

Comment: I did all of them are using a Node Class instead of the void class. They also have different parameters. So I'm out of luck.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I did draw it out and used the debugger. As I said, my front -> next = front -> prev; is the issue I just don't know what to change it out with because without it I cant grab the element behind front.

Comment: Unit test each operation. Otherwise, to brute force debug it, take the smallest possible input to produce an error, and see which step assigns an incorrect pointer.

Comment: Just glancing at this on a phone, you should probably move the recursion higher in the function body. Before you start messing with the nodes. Could be wrong but…

Comment: Depending on the amount of scaffolding you have in `List`, for example it tracks the head and tail of the list,  the `reverse` function could be as simple as `std::swap(front->prev, front->next); if(front->prev) { reverse(front->prev); }`. Unfortunately too much has been left out of the question and any answer I wrote would be mostly guesswork. Expand on the question with a [mre] to reduce or eliminate the number of guesses. and I'd be happy to show you exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help you understand what is going on if you draw out the state of your list on each step.

Your list looks like this upon entry to the initial call to `reverse()`:

```
        +-----------+    +-----------+    +----------+    +---------+
        | "Hello" [n] -> | "Human" [n] -> | "test" [n] -> | "Boo" [n] -> NULL
NULL <- [p]         | <- [p]         | <- [p]        | <- [p]       |
        +-----------+    +-----------+    +----------+    +---------+
        ^
        head
        front
```

1. `front` is not NULL, so you swap `front->next` and `front-prev`, and now the list looks like this:

```
   +-----------+          +-----------+    +----------+    +---------+
   | "Hello" [n] -> NULL  | "Human" [n] -> | "test" [n] -> | "Boo" [n] -> NULL
+- [p]         | <------- [p]         | <- [p]        | <- [p]       |
|  +-----------+          +-----------+    +----------+    +---------+
|  ^                      ^
|  head                   |
|  front                  |
+-------------------------+
```

`front->prev` is not NULL, so you execute `reverse(front->prev)`.

2. `front` is not NULL, so you swap `front->next` and `front-prev`, and now the list looks like this:

```
   +-------------------------------------+
   |                                     |
  \/                                     |
   +-----------+          +-----------+  |  +----------+    +---------+
   | "Hello" [n] -> NULL  | "Human" [n] -+  | "test" [n] -> | "Boo" [n] -> NULL
+- [p]         |       +- [p]         | <-- [p]        | <- [p]       |
|  +-----------+       |  +-----------+     +----------+    +---------+
|  ^                   |  ^ ^               ^
|  head                |  | front           |
|                      +--|-----------------+
+-------------------------+
```

`front->prev` is not NULL, so you execute `reverse(front->prev)`.

3. `front` is not NULL, so you swap `front->next` and `front-prev`, and now the list looks like this:

```
   +-------------------------------------+
   |                       +-------------|----------------+
  \/                      \/             |                |
   +-----------+          +-----------+  |  +----------+  |  +---------+
   | "Hello" [n] -> NULL  | "Human" [n] -+  | "test" [n] -+  | "Boo" [n] -> NULL
+- [p]         |       +- [p]         |  +- [p]        | <-- [p]       |
|  +-----------+       |  +-----------+  |  +----------+     +---------+
|  ^                   |  ^              |  ^ ^              ^
|  head                |  |              |  | front          |
|                      +--|--------------|--+                |
+-------------------------+              +-------------------+
```

`front->prev` is not NULL, so you execute `reverse(front->prev)`.

4. `front` is not NULL, so you swap `front->next` and `front-prev`, and now the list looks like this:

```
   +-------------------------------------+  +----------------------------------+
   |                      +--------------|--|-------------+                    |
  \/                     \/              | \/             |                    |
   +-----------+          +-----------+  |  +----------+  |       +---------+  |
   | "Hello" [n] -> NULL  | "Human" [n] -+  | "test" [n] -+       | "Boo" [n] -+
+- [p]         |       +- [p]         |  +- [p]        |  NULL <- [p]       |
|  +-----------+       |  +-----------+  |  +----------+          +---------+
|  ^                   |  ^              |  ^                     ^ ^
|  head                |  |              |  |                     | front
|                      +--|--------------|--+                     |
+-------------------------+              +------------------------+
```

And finally, `front->prev` is NULL, so you exit.

The above is a little messy, so let's re-draw it cleaner with the new arrows:

```
        +---------+    +----------+    +-----------+    +-----------+
        | "Boo" [n] -> | "test" [n] -> | "Human" [n] -> | "Hello" [n] -> NULL
NULL <- [p]       | <- [p]        | <- [p]         | <- [p]         |
        +---------+    +----------+    +-----------+    +-----------+
                                                        ^
                                                        head
```

Look, the nodes were reversed correctly!

However, notice anything wrong?  When you try to printout the new list, you only see `Hello`, because that is where `head` is still pointing!  You need to update `head` to point at `Boo` instead:

```
        +---------+    +----------+    +-----------+    +-----------+
        | "Boo" [n] -> | "test" [n] -> | "Human" [n] -> | "Hello" [n] -> NULL
NULL <- [p]       | <- [p]        | <- [p]         | <- [p]         |
        +---------+    +----------+    +-----------+    +-----------+
        ^
        head
```

If your `List` class is maintaining both `head` and `tail` pointers, you can simply swap them:

```
void List::reverse(Node *front)
{
    ...
}

void List::reverse()
{
    reverse(head);
    Node *temp = head;
    tail = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

But, if you don't have a `tail` pointer, then you will need to make `reverse()` return the new `head` pointer after its work is finished, eg:

```
Node* List::reverse(Node *front)
{
  ...
  if(front == NULL)
  {
    ...
    return NULL;
  }

  ...

  if(front->prev == NULL)
  {
    ...
    return front;
  }

  return reverse(front->prev);
}

void List::reverse()
{
    head = reverse(head);
}
```

Comment: Could it also be possible that I am missing a base case of setting my head to the new head of the list? My friend told me this was the issue.

Comment: @Andyrew that is what I said in my answer.. Of course you need to update `head` to point at the new head node.

Comment: Even if I did something like

`Node *lds = new Node;`

`lds = head;`

`reverse(lds->prev);`

This still wont work cuz its referring to `Hello`
Could it be that the recursive function wont print our every method into a list? Only just the end? 

My logic is just horrible right now. I've been at this bug for a long time.

Comment: @Andyrew `Node *lds = new Node; lds = head;` is a memory leak, and wrong logic anyway. Did you even read my answer all the way through to the end? I already explain how to fix the code.

Comment: Even with your implementation, it only prints `Hello` within the list. It most likely works. Just my monkey brain can't think.

Comment: @Andyrew [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/arB2SG). [So does this](https://ideone.com/jla3cF)

Comment: I fixed it. Your stuff didn't work for some reason. But I found the issue. I think we were getting different results because our toStrings methods were very different. I just fixed it up a bit and it works fine

Comment: @Andyrew "*Your stuff didn't work for some reason*" - I proved in my last comment that it works fine. You must not have incorporated it into your code correctly. But oh well, glad your code is working now.